# MVC - How to show the current int value in a Label in the View class?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

So basically I am making a yahtzee game in java using MVC and I need to display the score for each category, which I have done through a Label in the view next to the button. This code is in my View class which puts it on there

```
onesValueLabel = new Label(""+myController.getOnesValue());
        onesValueLabel.setBounds(620,80,30,20);
        this.add(onesValueLabel);
```

The problem I am foreseeing is that once view is pressed, the onesValueLabel will not be updated on screen even though the myController.getOnesValue() is changed.

How can I display the current value of myController.getOnesValue()) so that it can change on the view?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement some kind of [observe pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) , where by the view can "observe" changes in the model and update it's state.

This is commonly known as "listeners".

Basically, you provide an interface that describes one or more events that the model might raise (you can have multiple listeners if need be).

Any interested party would implement the interface and pass a reference to, or "register" with, the model.

When some event occurred, the model would fire this event, notifying all the registered listeners that something has happened.

How and what it is up to you.